# Changing excel formula result to value

Tags: vba, excel

I managed to run a macro that uses a formula to merge the value of column B and column C and saving the formula result to column D, but is there any method to change the formula to value and paste it to column B, deleting column C and column D. Below is the code used:

```
Sub LoopThroughFilesMergingFormula()

    'paste the specified directory to FolderName
    FolderName = "C:\Users\Desktop\formula merge"
    If Right(FolderName, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then FolderName = FolderName & Application.PathSeparator
    Fname = Dir(FolderName & "*.xlsx")

    'loop through the files
    Do While Len(Fname)

        With Workbooks.Open(FolderName & Fname)
             Range("D2").Formula = "=$B2 & "" "" & ""|"" & ""QTY: "" & $C2"
             Range("D2", "D" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown
         .Save
         .Close
        End With

        ' go to the next file in the folder
        Fname = Dir

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Google "`Paste Values Excel VBA`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it using the parent workbook/worksheet you set up..

```
    With Workbooks.Open(FolderName & Fname)
        with .worksheets(1)
            with .Range(.cells(2, "d"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).offset(0, 3))
                .formula = "=$B2 & "" "" & ""|"" & ""QTY: "" & $C2"
                .offset(0, -2) = .value
            end with
            .columns("c:d").entirecolumn.delete
        end with
        .Save
        .Close
    End With
```

Comment: I just realized there a type mismatch error if there is a only a single value present

Comment: see alternative above

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        With Workbooks.Open(FolderName & Fname)
         Do until Sheet1.Cells(x,2) = ""
           Sheet1.cells(x,4) = Sheet1.cells(x,2) & " | QTY: " & SHeet1.cells(x,3)
         x =x +1
         Loop
          .Save
          .Close
    End With
```

Comment: but my workbooks each have different sheet names according to the product number is there any way to change it ?

Comment: You will need to give the sheet name or reference.. i just gave you a path, now you will have to adjust as per your requirements. Keep learning. :)

Comment: Aren't the limits of the original defined by the last populated cell in column A?

Comment: all i took the reference from the Coloumn B and C, and assumed that the the values in Column B is non blank and kept that as a Unique column.